# Can you create a flag field for tokens based off of a dataframe column of tokens?

Tags: python, pandas, token

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Beverage        Ingredients                                                           Ingredients_Tokens
Orange Juice    Orange Juice Concentrate,  Orange Pulp                                [orange, juice, concentrate, orange, pulp]
Root Beer       Sugar, Water, Caramel Color                                           [sugar, water, caramel, color]
...             ...                                                                   ...
Apple Juice     INGREDIENTS: CONTAINS PURE FILTERED WATER,  CONCENTRATED APPLE JUICE  [pure, filtered, water, concentrated, apple, juice]
```

I want to take the ingredients_tokens field and create flag fields for each token that appears more than 20 times in the whole dataframe so that my final dataframe has all of the Beverages and whether they contain the tokens listed, like

```
Beverage               Token_Orange   Token_Sugar Token_Water ... Token_Apple
Orange_Juice                      1             0           0              0
Root Beer                         0             1           1              0
...
Apple Juice                       0             0           1              1
```

I tried a loop that tried to create the Token variable and then store it, something like (47 is total number of tokens):

```
df=pd.DataFrame() 
for i in range (0,47): 
     T['Token'] = T['Ingredients_Tokens'][i] 
     df = df.append([Q]) 

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

But am not sure where to go

Comment: What would token be?

Comment: I thought it would be to create a field that would be the first token from the Ingredients_Token field. Then I could create dummies for all of those token fields

Answer (score 0):

One option if you're on one of the more recent versions of `pandas` is to use `.explode`:

```
In [167]: df
Out[167]:
       thing            ingredients
0         oj  [orange, juice, pulp]
1  root beer          [roots, beer]

In [168]: df.explode("ingredients").set_index("ingredients", append=True).unstack().notnull()
Out[168]:
             thing
ingredients   beer  juice orange   pulp  roots
0            False   True   True   True  False
1             True  False  False  False   True
```